# How do I use MapStateListener?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have my android application using Google MAP API V2.
I want to handle touch, drag and untouch event on Map using this solution: https://github.com/MadsFrandsen/MapStateListener

But i cant get reference to TouchableMapFragment object from view to create MapStateListener.

I'm new with Android so please help me to implement this solution or another solution to solve my problem.
Thanks,

This's my layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="megacom.taxigo.driver.android.utils.mapstatelistener.TouchableMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: How are you creating the `TouchableMapFragment` object? Is it part of your XML layout or as part of your activity?

Comment: I add TouchableMapFragment to my layou:

Comment: <fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:name="megacom.taxigo.driver.android.utils.mapstatelistener.TouchableMapFragment"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `TouchableMapFragment` should be pretty simple. Let's assume you have a simple layout file called `map.xml` for example:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:name="megacom.taxigo.driver.android.utils.mapstatelistener.TouchableMapF‌​ragment"/>
```

Now in your Activity all you need to do is the following;

```
public void onCreate(Context context) {
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    TouchableMapFragment touchableMapFragment = (TouchableMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap map = touchableMapFragment.getMap();
    new MyMapStateListener(map, touchableMapFragment, this) {
        @Override
        public void onMapTouched() {
            // Map touched
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReleased() {
            // Map released
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapUnsettled() {
            // Map unsettled
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapSettled() {
            // Map settled
        }
    };
}
```

Something to watch out for when using a `MapFragment` the [getMap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()) method can return null if the fragment has not finished initialising.

Comment: @marcus.ramsden  Possible to share how would you combine this library with Marker setOnMarkerClickListener? I tried using this library and when press on any marker, code will always execute onMapSettled fuction

Comment: @simeh Unfortunately I was answering this based on my knowledge of fragments but not about the specific library. I would suggest you create a new question and see if someone else has had any experience with it. Looking quickly at the source though you may struggle with using the two together as it hijacks the touch events on the fragment.